# HttpContext.Current.User does not work in Azure Firebase Example

Tags: c#, asp.net, firebase, azure

I am attempting to build the example ASP.NET backend here (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/push-notifications-android-specific-users-firebase-cloud-messaging) for Firebase Notifications. The example code uses the `HttpContext.Current.User`, but this has apparently been depreciated (from reviewing a number of other StackOverflow questions and answers).

```
HttpContext.Current.User =
    new GenericPrincipal(new GenericIdentity(user), new string[0]);
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal =
    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User;
```

Neither of these lines work, and I have tried the answers from the other StackOverflow questions. What is the resolution to this?

Comment: I don't think `HttpContext.Current.User` has been depcrecated.  How do they 'not work' ?

Comment: HttpContext does not contain a definition for Current.
The other error is The type or namessapce name 'HttpContext' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web'

Comment: .NET core or .NET framework?

Comment: @Neil It is .NET Core

Comment: In .NET core, you can inject `IHttpContextAccessor` into your class, and use that instead.

Comment: @Neil Well, there's no more errors, so hopefully it works. Thanks!